# Oracle looping query to get value plus child values from same table

Tags: oracle

I have a table which contains values in a hierarchy structure.
I was wondering if anyone knew of a query where I could loop through each row finding it's ID and then search for rows with a PARENTID of the same value. So for example:

With a table

```
ID  PARENTID    LEVEL   VALUE
-------------------------------
1   0           COUNTRY USA
2   1           CITY    NYC
3   1           CITY    LA
4   2           TEAM    GIANTS
5   2           TEAM    JETS
6   3           TEAM    RAMS
7   3           TEAM    CHARGERS
```

I could start by searching for ID:2 (NYC) and from there find all teams in that city. Something like (but I do not know the total loops I'll need to do)

```
SELECT ID2,VALUE FROM TABLE1 WHERE PARENTID = ID1;
```

Gives me:

```
3,LA
6,RAMS
7,CHARGERS
```

Comment: You did share sample data, would you please also provide the expected results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connect by` is a common way to loop through a hierarchy like that. If you add `start with`, you can pick a starting point in the hierarchy.

```
SELECT table1.*, level
FROM table1
START WITH id = 3
CONNECT BY parentid = PRIOR id;
```

Please note that `level` is an Oracle keyword which will tell you how many loops you have stepped through so far. I wouldn't recommend using it as a column name. [There's some other pseudocolumns and functions you might find helpful too](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm).

Comment: It's just a pity I can only give this 1 up vote as this simple script does exactly what I'm looking for.I really need to learn how keywords like LEVEL work, because even with my START WITH ID as 451 it looks like this is finding everything in order.